# Leave One Out Cross-Validation for Conditional Inference Trees with a continuous outcome

Tags: r, binary-tree, cross-validation, loocv

I'm currently working on a project involving conditional inference trees in R using the partykit package, and I'm trying to perform Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV) because I have a small data set (N=300) for it to be partitioned into test and train data. I have come across LOOCV validation with the caret package but I cannot find the method ctree in the function train. My outcome variable is a continuous variable.

```
model <- ctree(duration ~ ., data = data)
```

I am wondering whether there is a function that I can use to perform LOOCV on the ctree.

I tried dividing the data in train and test data but the cross-validation returned low accuracy.

Comment: You can use `method = "ctree"` and set `trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV")` in `caret::train`.